# CUDA 3D to linear index mapping (Pitch)

Tags: 3d, cuda, pitch

I have 3-Dimensional data, and I am working on it using CUDA.

I am allocating memory using **cudaMallocPitch()**.

```
cudaMallocPitch((void **)&test_data, &pitch, sizeof(float)*N*N, N);
```

In the 2-D version of my code, where the dimension was N*N, I accessed a particular element by doing this:

```
i = blockIdx.x*BLOCK_X + threadIdx.x;
j = blockIdx.y*BLOCK_Y + threadIdx.y;
linearIdx = i + j*pitch/sizeof(float);
```

Now I wish to extend the code to 3-D. I can get the *z* index similarly

```
k = blockIdx.z*BLOCK_Z + threadIdx.z;
```

But how do I combine the three to get the linear index now? What exactly is *pitch* and how do I access the element now? Please comment if the method I am allocating memory for the 3-D data is right or not.

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't knew about this function (cudaMallocPitch), but it seems that there's a 3D version of it, which i found by following first google link on cudaMalloPitch cudaMallocPitch : http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10.html#g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10
So i guess you (who knew about it) could have find it too
the formula may be linearIdx = i + pitch.xsize * ( j + pitch.ysize * k)

Comment: Dear @user2774555, It would be great if you revirew the answer and accept one of them or even, edit your question with new information if none helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple good examples in the programming guide for 2D and 3D arrays. They are as following:

2D:

```
// Host code
int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch,
                width * sizeof(float), height);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPtr, pitch, width, height);

// Device code
__global__ void MyKernel(float* devPtr,
                         size_t pitch, int width, int height)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) {
        float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
        for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {
            float element = row[c];
        }
    }
}
```

3D:

```
// Host code
int width = 64, height = 64, depth = 64;
cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(width * sizeof(float),
                                    height, depth);
cudaPitchedPtr devPitchedPtr;
cudaMalloc3D(&devPitchedPtr, extent);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPitchedPtr, width, height, depth);

// Device code
__global__ void MyKernel(cudaPitchedPtr devPitchedPtr,
                         int width, int height, int depth)
{
    char* devPtr = devPitchedPtr.ptr;
    size_t pitch = devPitchedPtr.pitch;
    size_t slicePitch = pitch * height;
    for (int z = 0; z < depth; ++z) {
        char* slice = devPtr + z * slicePitch;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            float* row = (float*)(slice + y * pitch);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                float element = row[x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With 2D arrays it is easy to see the usage of pitch. The reason they cast the array pointer into a `char*` is that pitch returns a Byte size, not a number of elements (pitch could be non multiple of element size).

With 3D arrays this is simply extended using the height of each 2D array. This is analogous to unrolling the 3D structure into many 2D slices.

Comment: You are not making use of the blockIdx and threadIdx here.. Thanks for suggesting the cudaMalloc3D() function, but how do I incorporate the thread indices and block indices?

Comment: There's a few different ways depending on the size of the 3D structure. You could allocate a block to each 2D slice of the array and then use a 2D block structure to loop through blocks of the elements. You could use a block per 2D slice then use a 1D block to loop through the rows of each 2D slice. Is there a particular mapping you were interested in?

Answer (score 0):

The memory is a 1D continuous space of bytes. The 1D, 2D and 3D access pattern depends on how you are interpreting your data and also how you are accessing them by 1D, 2D and 3D blocks of threads.

> **cudaMallocPitch** Allocates at least width (in bytes) * height bytes of linear memory on the device. The function **may pad the allocation** to ensure that corresponding pointers in any given row will continue to meet the alignment requirements for coalescing as the address is updated from row to row. **The pitch** returned in *pitch by cudaMallocPitch() **is the width in bytes of the allocation**. -- Memory Management
>   [CUDA Runtime API].

In the case of data of `M (rows) x N (cols) x K (slices)` each pixel of one slice will be at

```
i = blockIdx.x*BLOCK_X + threadIdx.x;
j = blockIdx.y*BLOCK_Y + threadIdx.y;

linearIdx = i + j*pitch/sizeof(float);
```

The next slice of pixels is `M x N` positions separated. So, to access your data you must correctly *jump* to the next slice. that is,

```
i = blockIdx.x*BLOCK_X + threadIdx.x;
j = blockIdx.y*BLOCK_Y + threadIdx.y;
// index for the slice
k = blockIdx.z*BLOCK_Z + threadIdx.z;

// for the sake of simplicity 
int next_row_pitched = pitch/sizeof(float);

linearIdx = i + j*next_row_pitched + k*next_row_pitched*N;
```

To get the 'third' dimension you must 'jump' all the pixel of one slice, that is, `M x N` positions. As each row is pitched, you must change `M` by the pitched value returned by cudaMallockPitch.

The above indexing is valid if you launch 3D blocks of threads. You can also launch 2D blocks of threads and then iterate the number of slices.

The Chapter 3.2.2 Device Memory of the CUDA C Programming Guide has a code sample that allocates a width×height×depth 3D array of floating-point values and shows how to loop over the array elements in device code.